# Get Rows With At Least Two Non Zero Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  key integer NOT NULL AI ,
  name varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column1 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column2 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column3 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column4 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column5 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column6 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (key)
)
```

Now I want to have a sql which get me rows which have atleast two columns values non zero for columns column1 to column6.

e.g. if we have rows

```
1 TEST 0 0 6 1 0 5
2 ABCD 0 0 0 0 0 5
3 DEFG 0 0 4 1 0 5
4 HIJK 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

so my query should return ID 1 and 3 as they have atleast 2 non zero columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person
WHERE (column1 <> 0 + column2 <> 0 + column3 <> 0 + 
       column4 <> 0 + column5 <> 0 + column6 <> 0
      ) > 1;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.key 
            FROM (SELECT p.key, p.column1 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column1 <> 0
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT p.key, p.column2 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column2 <> 0
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT p.key, p.column3 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column3 <> 0
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT p.key, p.column4 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column4 <> 0
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT p.key, p.column5 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column5 <> 0
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT p.key, p.column6 AS columnData FROM person p WHEN p.column6 <> 0
                 ) AS A 
            GROUP BY A.key 
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
           ) AS A ON p.key = A.key;
```

Comment: THe sub select will be quite efficient, the initial (simply counting non-zero fields) is much clearer and more efficient.  While the second alternative would work, I would recommend removing it from the answer.

Comment: Don't you need UNION ALL in the second alternative? (Just in case col1 = col2)

Comment: Your first solution didn't work in SQL fiddle. I'm not sure why because JeurgenD's solution does.

Comment: The first solution works well for me, but I needed to wrap each `columnx <> 0` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of 0 columns:

```
where case when c1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end + case when c2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end ... >= 2
```

Comment: Easier to use the first result, taking advantage of adding boolean results where true becomes 1 and false is zero